# How to encrypt a string using RSA algorithm and PKCS1_PADDING not OAEP and print the encrypted string in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, phpseclib

Here is the code I am using but I keep getting a blank `echo`. How can I `echo` the encrypted text.

```
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey.txt'));
$rsa->loadKey($rsa->getPublicKey());
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
echo $rsa->encrypt('1234567890');
```

Comment: Please specify what `'Crypt/RSA.php'` contains. How should we be able to answer without?

Comment: Assuming that `'Crypt/RSA.php'` refers to php's "Crypt_RSA" pear package (outdated and unmaintained) I checked that one. Apparently there is no method `loadKey()` defined in there. are you sure it does exist in your version? Are you certain you do not get any errors yourself? Did you check your http servers error log file when not using php in CLI?

Comment: @Santhucool If you suggest edits, please try to fix all the issues in the post. This includes formatting (indentation), tags and title.

Comment: Works for me. I get some string as output that looks somehow garbled (obviously I cannot say of that is "encrypted"). So back to what I wrote above: any error you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error or response.

Comment: I'd first check to make sure that the key is valid. Doing `echo "$rsa";` is usually a good test of that. After that I'd do `echo gettype($rsa->encrypt('123457890'))`. Is what's being returned a false or is it a string with some special characters in it that are messing up your terminal? Maybe try `echo bin2hex($rsa->encrypt('12345567890'))` as well if it's a string.